# Caps Lock not working

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, capslock

My Caps Lock key on my keyboard is not working.

The light indicator does not come on and nothing is capitalized when typing.

What do i need to do to fix this issue.

`xmodmap -e "add Lock = Caps_Lock"` did not work.

Swapped out other keyboards and still have the same results. The Caps Lock is working on all three on windows.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Are you sure its not hardware issue?

Comment: Swapped out for 2 other keyboards and all have the same result.

Comment: Only Caps Lock? Have you check others?

Comment: All other keys appear to be working besides `Caps Lock` and `Scroll Lock`. I do not care about `Scroll Lock` but `Caps Lock` is killing me.

Comment: LAWL. A co-worker played a prank on me. =D He disabled my scroll lock when using my computer the other day. He changed my `Keyboard layout options` under `keyboard layout` to make my `Ctrl` key to act as my `Caps Lock`.

Comment: Ohhh thats nice partner :3

Comment: It seems to me that we should actually **not** close this as *too localized*, because there are situations outside this very narrow one (of being intentionally pranked) where unexpected settings in keyboard layout options could cause this problem. (For example, someone could have forgotten setting it themselves, or they may have gotten the computer from someone else who modified that setting.) The answer here may be helpful to more people; I think this question should remain open.

Comment: I was thinking it may be too localized and considered closing it, but i figured the information might still be helpful for someone else. So i decided to leave it open. The scenario may be localized but the problem and solution are not. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

LAWL. I got pranked. =/

A co-worker disabled my scroll lock when using my computer the other day. He changed my `Keyboard layout options` under `keyboard layout` to make my `Ctrl` key to act as my `Caps Lock`.

Got to Settings -> Keyboard Layout -> Options.

There was a `Ctrl key position` and he had `Caps Lock as Ctrl` selected.

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I don't see an Options area. It seems Gnome removed the options, but you can get to it here: https://mikewilliamson.wordpress.com/2014/03/31/changing-keyboard-layout-options-in-ubuntu-14-04/