# Caps lock key doesn't work

Tags: keyboard, capslock

I've installed Ubuntu 15.04 on my sister's laptop but the Caps lock key doesn't work.
She uses a french keyboard.

Where could this problem come from and how to fix it please ?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Best regards,

Peace :)

Jesus

Comment: Have you tried this ? 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/196474/caps-lock-not-working

Comment: Hi, can you please run `xev -event keyboard` try pressing escape and see what it prints. Please paste it here.

Comment: Ok, I have sent the message to my sister and I'm waiting for the answer. I will let you know.

Comment: No problem, funny that that user name was available.

Comment: I tried and I won ;) A miracle... Probably ;)

Comment: Ok, so I have the result of your command Trygve : KeymapNotify event, serial 24, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  4294967237 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

Comment: ClientMessage event, serial 25, synthetic YES, window 0x3200001,
    message_type 0x144 (WM_PROTOCOLS), format 32, message 0x142 (WM_DELETE_WINDOW)
cath@cath:~$ KeymapNotify event, serial 24, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
KeymapNotify : command not found
cath@cath:~$     keys:  4294967237 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
keys: : command not found
cath@cath:~$            0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
0 : command not found

Comment: I solved this for Ubuntu 18.04 with https://askubuntu.com/questions/1060354/caps-lock-stopped-working-after-an-update.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. it worked for me.
First off. If the key works before passing the login screen and doesn't after it, then continue reading :D . 
Go to settings > keyboard > Typing Look at (compose key) and (Alternative Characters Key) if any of them is assigned to Caps Lock change it to be something else (disable it if possible)  the caps lock will work normally

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try it as soon as I see my sister. I'll let you know.

Comment: Well.. I forgot to say that I am taking about Ubuntu Gnome 14.4 :-D

Comment: Is it funny to anyone else that @JesusChrist promised to report back, but never returned?